# Покраска прогресс-бара

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

По макету прогресс-бары должны выглядеть так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в IE и Edge они окрашены в синий цвет, при том, что стили для этих браузеров(как для старых, так и для новых версий прописаны):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, помогите, пожалуйста.)
HTML

```
<div class="graph-wrapper">
<ul>
    <li class="progress progress_first">
        <progress value="11" max="15" class="ProgressBar__line"></progress>
        <i class="ProgressBar__text">​Ручное бронирование</i>​
        <i class="current current-first">11</i>
    </li>


    <li class="progress progress_second">
        <progress value="3" max="15" class="ProgressBar__line"></progress>
        <i class="ProgressBar__text">​Пакетные туры</i>​
        <i class="current current-second">3</i>
    </li>

    <li class="progress progress_third">
        <progress value="1" max="15" class="ProgressBar__line"></progress>
        <i class="ProgressBar__text">​Отели</i>​
        <i class="current current-third">1</i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS скину скриншотом, поскольку не принимает сам код.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Проще и надёжнее переделать прогресс-бары простыми div'ами

Comment: Тут есть специальная кнопка вставки кода, там и css и js и html (Ctrl+M) и т.д. можно вставлять. Лучше поправьте сообщение, будет больше шансов что помогут

Comment: Всегда код принимает. Если тут не получается, скинули бы ссылку на какой-нибудь ресурс вроде jsfiddle.

Comment: @andreymal Пожалуй, вы правы. Время есть,попробую переделать. Спасибо)

Comment: @Nilsan При вставке CSS кода, в окно заносилось только первые 4 строки, остальные же были как простой текст и совсем не читаемо...

Comment: @Friendly33, вы скорее всего пытаетесь вставить "Пример кода", а через одну иконку есть "Фрагмент кода", который всегда вставляется as-is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Нативные элементы в каждом браузере реализованы по своему и не всегда можно их стилизовать. Такой-то элемент можно и самому сверстать

Comment: Все верно, но в документации говорится, что "filter:..." как раз таки отвечает за отображение цветов в IE 6-9, но это уже не важно, так как решил переделать, ведь действительно проще будет.